# LinkedIn API OAuth2 - Unable to retrieve access token

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get an access token on the LinkedIn API but I get the following error :

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Unable to retrieve access token: appid or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired"}
```

PHP code :

Get the authorization code (work):

```
$linkedIn = array(
        'clientId' => 'My id',
        'redirectUri' => WEBSITE.'User/liCallback/',
        'state' => 'rz5t4er6t7re68t7e6rt6ze9',
        'scope' => 'r_basicprofile'
    );
    $liLoginUrl = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id='.$linkedIn['clientId'].'&redirect_uri='.$linkedIn['redirectUri'].'?state='.$linkedIn['state'].'&scope='.$linkedIn['scope'];
```

Get the access toekn (doesn't work) :

```
 public function liCallback(){
  $linkedin =   array(
      'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
      'code' => $this->get('code'),
      'redirectUri' => WEBSITE.'User/liCallback/',
      'client_id' => 'My id',
      'client_secret' => 'My client secret'
  );



  $curl_handle=curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken');
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  echo curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type='.$linkedin['grant_type'].'&code='.$this->get('code').'&redirect_uri='.urlencode($linkedin['redirectUri']).'&client_id='.$linkedin['client_id'].'&client_secret='.$linkedin['client_secret']);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'x-www-form-urlencoded');
  $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
  var_dump($query);
  curl_close($curl_handle);

}
```

I try to use encodeurl() but I got the same error.
I try with file_get_content() but I got an 400 error.

Thanks for help !

Comment: Somebody can help me ?

Comment: Up ? Somebody can help me ?

Comment: `file_get_content()` would not work as linkedin require extra header which can not be set on `file_get_content()`

Comment: @mdck are you able to solve this?